# Problems uploading with a new Nano

Tags: arduino-nano, bootloader

My first post - I am a relative newbie.

I want to make a smartcontroller for my boat - I have built the electronics and written and tested a sketch for the Nano, all working totally fine. I then decided that I would  like to keep my existing Nano (Nano-A) as a development system and buy another one (Nano-B) to actually deploy. Both of these are cheap chinese clones (from different suppliers).

However I cannot upload anything to Nano-B. It seems to be basically working (LEDs flash) but not wishing to accept any sketch uploads. The COM port seems to be working OK and I have tried all the various options available in the Arduino IDE (boards, programmers etc.) without success.

So I came to the conclusion that possibly the bootloader on Nano-B needs to be re-flashed.

So I setup Nano-A as a programmer, loaded up "ArduinoISP", connected up the ISP pins and hit "burn bootloader".

It seems as if this is "nearly working". I have turned on the -v (verbose) option for avrdude and pasted the log below. It looks to me as if the IDE is invoking avrdude twice; (1) To set the Fuses etc, and (2) to upload the actual bootloader. I seems that (1) is working OK but (2) is failing.

I've been tearing my hair out for about 3 weeks with this and would be really keen to get some ideas.
Thanks in advance.

Arduino "burn bootloader" IDE Log - follows;

```
Arduino: 1.8.13 (Windows Store 1.8.42.0) (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino Nano, ATmega328P"

C:\Users\--\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\arduino\tools\avrdude\6.3.0-arduino17/bin/avrdude -CC:\Users\--\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\arduino\tools\avrdude\6.3.0-arduino17/etc/avrdude.conf -v -patmega328p -cstk500v1 -PCOM8 -b19200 -e -Ulock:w:0x3F:m -Uefuse:w:0xFD:m -Uhfuse:w:0xDA:m -Ulfuse:w:0xFF:m 



avrdude: Version 6.3-20190619

         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/

         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch



         System wide configuration file is "C:\Users\--\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\arduino\tools\avrdude\6.3.0-arduino17/etc/avrdude.conf"



         Using Port                    : COM8

         Using Programmer              : stk500v1

         Overriding Baud Rate          : 19200

         AVR Part                      : ATmega328P

         Chip Erase delay              : 9000 us

         PAGEL                         : PD7

         BS2                           : PC2

         RESET disposition             : dedicated

         RETRY pulse                   : SCK

         serial program mode           : yes

         parallel program mode         : yes

         Timeout                       : 200

         StabDelay                     : 100

         CmdexeDelay                   : 25

         SyncLoops                     : 32

         ByteDelay                     : 0

         PollIndex                     : 3

         PollValue                     : 0x53

         Memory Detail                 :



                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled

           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack

           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------

           eeprom        65    20     4    0 no       1024    4      0  3600  3600 0xff 0xff

           flash         65     6   128    0 yes     32768  128    256  4500  4500 0xff 0xff

           lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00

           hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00

           efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00

           lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00

           calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

           signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00



         Programmer Type : STK500

         Description     : Atmel STK500 Version 1.x firmware

         Hardware Version: 2

         Firmware Version: 1.18

         Topcard         : Unknown

         Vtarget         : 0.0 V

         Varef           : 0.0 V

         Oscillator      : Off

         SCK period      : 0.1 us



avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions



Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.11s



avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e950f (probably m328p)

avrdude: erasing chip

avrdude: reading input file "0x3F"

avrdude: writing lock (1 bytes):



Writing | ################################################## | 100% 0.04s



avrdude: 1 bytes of lock written

avrdude: verifying lock memory against 0x3F:

avrdude: load data lock data from input file 0x3F:

avrdude: input file 0x3F contains 1 bytes

avrdude: reading on-chip lock data:



Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.04s



avrdude: verifying ...

avrdude: 1 bytes of lock verified

avrdude: reading input file "0xFD"

avrdude: writing efuse (1 bytes):



Writing | ################################################## | 100% 0.04s



avrdude: 1 bytes of efuse written

avrdude: verifying efuse memory against 0xFD:

avrdude: load data efuse data from input file 0xFD:

avrdude: input file 0xFD contains 1 bytes

avrdude: reading on-chip efuse data:



Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.04s



avrdude: verifying ...

avrdude: 1 bytes of efuse verified

avrdude: reading input file "0xDA"

avrdude: writing hfuse (1 bytes):



Writing | ################################################## | 100% 0.04s



avrdude: 1 bytes of hfuse written

avrdude: verifying hfuse memory against 0xDA:

avrdude: load data hfuse data from input file 0xDA:

avrdude: input file 0xDA contains 1 bytes

avrdude: reading on-chip hfuse data:



Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.04s



avrdude: verifying ...

avrdude: 1 bytes of hfuse verified

avrdude: reading input file "0xFF"

avrdude: writing lfuse (1 bytes):



Writing | ################################################## | 100% 0.04s



avrdude: 1 bytes of lfuse written

avrdude: verifying lfuse memory against 0xFF:

avrdude: load data lfuse data from input file 0xFF:

avrdude: input file 0xFF contains 1 bytes

avrdude: reading on-chip lfuse data:



Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.04s



avrdude: verifying ...

avrdude: 1 bytes of lfuse verified



avrdude done.  Thank you.



C:\Users\--\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\arduino\tools\avrdude\6.3.0-arduino17/bin/avrdude -CC:\Users\--\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\arduino\tools\avrdude\6.3.0-arduino17/etc/avrdude.conf -v -patmega328p -cstk500v1 -PCOM8 -b19200 -Uflash:w:C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.42.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\hardware\arduino\avr/bootloaders/optiboot/optiboot_atmega328.hex:i -Ulock:w:0x0F:m 



avrdude: Version 6.3-20190619

         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/

         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch



         System wide configuration file is "C:\Users\--\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\arduino\tools\avrdude\6.3.0-arduino17/etc/avrdude.conf"



         Using Port                    : COM8

         Using Programmer              : stk500v1

         Overriding Baud Rate          : 19200

         AVR Part                      : ATmega328P

         Chip Erase delay              : 9000 us

         PAGEL                         : PD7

         BS2                           : PC2

         RESET disposition             : dedicated

         RETRY pulse                   : SCK

         serial program mode           : yes

         parallel program mode         : yes

         Timeout                       : 200

         StabDelay                     : 100

         CmdexeDelay                   : 25

         SyncLoops                     : 32

         ByteDelay                     : 0

         PollIndex                     : 3

         PollValue                     : 0x53

         Memory Detail                 :



                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled

           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack

           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------

           eeprom        65    20     4    0 no       1024    4      0  3600  3600 0xff 0xff

           flash         65     6   128    0 yes     32768  128    256  4500  4500 0xff 0xff

           lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00

           hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00

           efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00

           lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00

           calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

           signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00



         Programmer Type : STK500

         Description     : Atmel STK500 Version 1.x firmware

         Hardware Version: 2

         Firmware Version: 1.18

         Topcard         : Unknown

         Vtarget         : 0.0 V

         Varef           : 0.0 V

         Oscillator      : Off

         SCK period      : 0.1 us



avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions



Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.11s



avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e950f (probably m328p)

avrdude: NOTE: "flash" memory has been specified, an erase cycle will be performed

         To disable this feature, specify the -D option.

avrdude: erasing chip

avrdude: reading input file "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.42.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\hardware\arduino\avr/bootloaders/optiboot/optiboot_atmega328.hex"

avrdude: writing flash (32768 bytes):



Writing | ################################################## | 100% 0.00s



avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_cmd(): programmer is out of sync

avrdude: stk500_cmd(): programmer is out of sync

avrdude: stk500_cmd(): programmer is out of sync

avrdude: 32768 bytes of flash written

avrdude: verifying flash memory against C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.42.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\hardware\arduino\avr/bootloaders/optiboot/optiboot_atmega328.hex:

avrdude: load data flash data from input file C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.42.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\hardware\arduino\avr/bootloaders/optiboot/optiboot_atmega328.hex:

avrdude: input file C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.42.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\hardware\arduino\avr/bootloaders/optiboot/optiboot_atmega328.hex contains 32768 bytes

avrdude: reading on-chip flash data:



Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.00s



avrdude: loadaddr(): (b) protocol error, expect=0x14, resp=0x3f



avrdude: stk500_paged_load(): (a) protocol error, expect=0x14, resp=0x10

avrdude: stk500_cmd(): protocol error

avr_read(): error reading address 0x7e01

    read operation not supported for memory "flash"

avrdude: failed to read all of flash memory, rc=-2

avrdude: stk500_disable(): protocol error, expect=0x14, resp=0xff



avrdude done.  Thank you.



Error while burning bootloader.
```

Edit ... Connections between the Arduinos. Nano A is the programmer. Nano B is the target

- Nano A    Nano B
- ISP 1  --     ISP 1 (MISO)
- ISP 2  --     ISP 2 (VCC - 5v)
- ISP 3  --     ISP 3 (SCK)
- ISP 4  --     ISP 4 (MOSI)
- ISP 6  --     ISP 6 (GND)
- D10    --     ISP 5 (RESET)

I have also now added a 60ohm resistor between RESET and +5V on Nano A
I have also tried connecting a capacitor between RESET and GND. (2uF and 100uF - I didn't have a 10uF) - but it made no difference

Further investigations.

I have tried running avrdude in "terminal" mode and can confirm that I can do all of the usual read/write operations except writing to anywhere in flash memory. This seems to be the only operation that does not work. I will now try breaking down the flash write operation into the individual SPI programming instructions to see if I can work out where it is failing. I suspect that my MCU is a "brick" but I have learned loads!

Another edit;
I have now been using the avrdude terminal mode "send" command to step throuh the individual SPI operations one at a time to write flash memory and hey! it works! (see below)
[image: Windows command interpreter - avrdude session]

So, if this works, why does ArduinoISP fail to load the bootloader?
I will set this up as another/new question

Comment: What, if anything, did you do with the reset signal on the nano that runs the arduinoisp.ino sketch?

Comment: Could you show how you've connected both Nano's?

Comment: I have connected the two nanos using the 6 pin ISP headers. as follows;

Comment: @RobW: please [edit] your question to add details, don't add them as comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now fixed this problem, but still do not fully understand what the original problem was.

Please see my other post on this qusetion to see what I did
[Link to other post](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/79909/cant-get-burn-bootloader-working-arduino-nano)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this isn't the answer to the bootloader issue but I went through the same thing recently, I realized a little late about what was exactly the problem, so I checked the uC on the Nano Board and it has an ATMega168 instead of the normal ATMega328p.

So if you are using ArduinoIDE you need to check the ATMega168 option while you are selecting your uC chip (as in the picture above)... Sometimes (as it happened to me, just going for the basics solve all the problems)

Hope this could help you mate

[image]

Comment: Thanks Cyborg. I had a look at the uC and it is an ATMega328p. Interestingly (perhaps) it is a lot bigger that the uC that is on the other Nano - also a 328p

Comment: Yeah mate, this link may help you to learn something new about ATMega328p packages: https://www.eeweb.com/the-different-atmega328-packages/

Answer (score 0):

There is more then one bootloader in the Nano's, a new one and the old one. I had the same problem so I simply went to tools in the IDE and switched from the new  to the old, it solved my problems.

Comment: Thanks Gil - This is one of the first things that I tried - without success.

Comment: Sorry I am out of ideas. I hope somebody can help you.